# Problem when using with overflow-x: scroll and justify-content: center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having issue while using overflow-x: scroll and justify-content: center on flex parent container.
Please see my code below.

issue: first flex child item is not showing it is crop in left or other all child item. please see my screenshot and code below.

I need your help. thank you in advance.

[image: issue screenshot here]

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `justify-content: center` is making the content to align to center, and some of the left is cut off. You could remove it and try.

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x:scroll
}
.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}
 
.box {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank for your quick response.

But i need center align when container has one or two child item

Comment: May be you could try some JS solution here. The box count exceeding a number could remove justify-content

Answer (score 0):

remove `"justify-content:center"`. And you said that you need center aligned elements when there are only 1 or 2 elements...so the answer is they will by aligned automatically...if there will be only two elements each of them will have `250px` width and if there will be only one then width of this element will be `500px`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
But i need center align when container has few item like one or two child item.

Comment: I explained you everything just try and you will understand.

Comment: @sabirsam The suggestion to remove `justify-content:center` is correct, what is missing is to add auto-margins to first and lest elements, so that free space is distributed specifically to them, and only in correct direction: `.box {margin-left: auto;} .box:last-child {margin-right: auto;}`